# how to upload base64 str by plupload

Tags: plupload

- I make a base64 string transform to File object, and add the object
  to ‘upload object’ in the methond addFiled.

  'upload.files.length === 0' after upload.addFile(fileObj);
- I can't config the params. if i use upload.setOption({url:'xxx'}), it
  is  will be throw that the error of 'url of null'.

  ```
  var cans = document.getElementById('cans');
  var ctx = cans.getContext("2d");

  var img = document.getElementById('img');

  img.onload = function () {

      ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 100, 100);

      var dataURL = cans.toDataURL();

      function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
          var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
              bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
          while (n--) {
              u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
          }
          return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
      }

      const fileObj = dataURLtoFile(dataURL, 'img.png');

      var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
          runtimes: 'html5',
          url: 'http://oss.aliyuncs.com',

          init: {
              PostInit: function () {

              },

              FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                 console.log(files,33);
              },

              FileUploaded: function (up, file, info) {
                  if (info.status == 200) {
                      alert('success');
                  }
                  else {
                      alert('error');
                  }
              },

              Error: function (up, err) {
                  console.log(err);
              }
          }
      });

      uploader.init();

      document.getElementById('uploadBtn').onclick = function () {

          uploader.addFile(fileObj,'');
          console.log(uploader.files);// [ ];

          //uploader.start();
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Please ask a specific question, so people can help you. What is your actual problem with the code?